# Wifi Connection Problems Dual Booting Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot

So, I recently started dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 with my Windows 10 laptop, and I've noticed that even though Ubuntu detects and connects to WiFi correctly, it doesn't actually work. I get all sorts of "no internet connection" errors, for example when using my browser. This doesn't happen at all when I switch back to windows. What could be the problem? Thanks.